# How does Tcl "file rename {*}[glob *tcl] dir/ " operate

Tags: tcl

I am trying to move a large number of files using Tcl and came across the expression : 
    `file rename {*}[glob *tcl] dir/` which works perfectly. 
Can anyone explain how this command works  or what this feature is called?

Comment: documentation: [glob](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/glob.htm), [Argument expansion.](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M9)

Answer (score 2):

It's a compound of two commands and some useful syntax.

- `glob` returns a *list* of filenames that match the pattern, `*tcl` in your case, or an error if nothing matches. There's a bunch of options you could use to modify what it returns, but you're not using any of them; that's great for your use case.
- `file rename` will rename files or *move files around*. In particular, when the final argument is an existing directory name, the other arguments are files (or directories) that will be moved into that directory. (That it moves things around is sensible if you're familiar with how POSIX system calls work.)

The final piece of the puzzle is `{*}[`…`]`, i.e., *command expansion*, which runs a command (which is `glob *tcl` in your case) and uses the elements of the list it returns as a sequence of arguments to the command call within which it is used. Which is useful; we want a list of filenames at that point of the call to `file rename`. There's no real limit on the number of arguments that can be moved around that way, other than basic things like memory and so on.

The `{*}` prefix (it's only special at the start of a word) can be used with other well-formed ways of producing a Tcl word (e.g., a read from a variable with `$` or a literal with `{…}`) or even with a compound word, though use with compound words is usually a sign that what you're doing is probably unwise.

---

If you have old Tcl code, written for Tcl 8.4 or before, you won't see `{*}`. Instead, you'd see something like this:

```
eval file rename [glob *tcl] dir/
```

```
# Or, more properly, one of these horrors:
eval {file rename} [glob *tcl] {dir/}
eval [list file rename] [glob *tcl] [list dir/]
eval [linsert [linsert [glob *tcl] 0 file rename] end dir/]
```

These were notoriously awkward to get right in tricky cases (causing many subtle bugs). The expansion syntax was added in Tcl 8.5 exactly to get rid of this whole class of trouble. `eval` still exists in modern Tcl, but it is now thankfully rarely used.